# Module nziv not found in QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, nviz

I want to use nviz in QGIS2.10.1-Pisa on windows 7 and I always get the same warning message  : "Module nviz not found", whenever I click on it in the GRASS tools Modules list. 
I have tried to uninstall and re-install from a fresh download (Standalone installer) to no avail.
I know there are some similar questions that have already been asked, but as far as I know there are no solutions.
any help?